# What species of bird is in this recording?

Tags: birds, animal-identification

Anyone recognize the bird call in the first 20 secs of this recording:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8sb5jjx3maeuk4o/Birdcall_Sept_Bethesda.m4a?dl=0

Recorded in Bethesda, Maryland in September of 2015.

Thanks.